# What is the replacement for bulkloader tool to download a CSV from the AppEngine data store?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to download a CSV of all entities of a particular type to do some local analysis.

There used to be the bulkloader tool, but references to it are disappearing from the internet, and I am not able to find a good replacement.

[Edit:]
Here is a blog about bulkloader that now has dead links:
http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Using-the-new-bulkloader

Comment: You can still generate the config yaml and do the download with appcfg.py ... but the documentation for that seems to have disappeared :(

Comment: Yeah, and the tool to generate the bulkloader.yaml in the first place is no longer available. :(

Comment: Are you looking for datastore admin?  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin

Comment: I looked at that, it lets me download data in Blobstore or Google Cloud Storage.  If I had a simple way to make that into CSV, that would solve the problem, but this seems to be only for porting to specific other Google systems.

Comment: "appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config" is still a thing that seems to work.

Comment: Yep. I guess the thing that's gone is the bulkloader tool that created bulkloader.yaml templates.  If I didn't have my old templates, I would have to write them manually from scratch, and there is no documentation about them.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just roll your own?

```
query = Model.all().order('date').fetch(1000)

output = "Date, val1, val2, val3, val4, etc.<br />"

for row in range(0, len(query)):
    output = output + ','.join([ str(query[row].date), str(query[row].val1), str(query[row].val2), ...., '<br />' ])

print output
```

Comment: This would run out into timeout issues with the size of the datastore that I have.

Comment: use a backend or structure it into chunks with tasks.

Comment: OK, sure, I can code this, but AppEngine used to provide a tool that did this really simply and well: bulkloader.  That tool appears to have been taken off the internet, and my question is trying to track down the replacement for the tool.